# MySQL Grouping by ID and Ordering by MIN(price)

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, min

OK, so I have following MySQL statement...

The goal is to group all the products "in stock" by their "id" codes and display the one with the "minimum price".

I had thought grouping by id alone and adding the MIN(price) in the ORDER BY clause would do the job, but apparently not...

```
SELECT *  
FROM (`products`)  
WHERE `in_stock` = 'yes'  
GROUP BY `id`  
ORDER BY brand, line, product, size, unit, MIN(price)  
LIMIT 25
```

Can someone help?

Sample data:

```
id  brand   line        product size    unit    price   url
123 Adidas  Deep Energy EDT 50  ml  10.00   Link1
123 Adidas  Deep Energy EDT 50  ml  8.75    Link2
123 Adidas  Deep Energy EDT 50  ml  9.99    Link3
124 Adidas  Deep Energy EDT 100 ml  15.00   Link4
```

So, effectively the query I'm trying to put together would return rows 2 and 4 of above sample data (minimum priced rows for "123" and "124")

Comment: To have a clearer idea of your problem, it would probably help to see some example data and your intended results.

Comment: Sorry, yes - edited @eggyal

Answer (score 1):

You calculate the minimum price as:

```
SELECT id, MIN(price)   
FROM products
WHERE in_stock = 'yes'  
GROUP BY id ;
```

To get the rows with the minimum prices, you need to join that back in:

```
select p.*
from products p join
     (SELECT id, MIN(price) as minprice  
      FROM products
      WHERE in_stock = 'yes'  
      GROUP BY id 
     ) pmin
     on p.id = pmin.id and p.price = pmin.minprice;
```